# how to randomly generate a date between a vector of start dates and end dates

Tags: r, random, lubridate, sample

i have a data frame of vectors of start dates and end dates:

| start_date | end_date | ind |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2/1/2023 | 2/15/2023 | 0 |
| 3/4/2023 | 4/17/2023 | 1 |
| 4/4/2023 | 4/31/2023 | 1 |

new data frame:

| start_date | end_date | random_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2/1/2023 | 2/15/2023 | 0 |
| 3/4/2023 | 4/17/2023 | 3/31/2023 |
| 4/4/2023 | 4/31/2023 | 4/30/2023 |

I'm looking for generate a random date for a vector for the rows that show an indicator

here is my attempt:

```
random_date <- as.Date(sample(as.numeric(df$start_date): as.numeric(df$end_date), 1, replace = T), origin = "1970-01-01")
```

**Edited so I can get a time saving solution**

Comment: Create a sequence between start and end dates and use `sample()` to generate the random dates that fall in that range. Can we see your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

With `map2_vec`:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(random_date = map2_vec(start_date, end_date, \(x, y) sample(seq.Date(x, y, by = "day"), 1)))

#  start_date   end_date random_date
#1 2023-02-01 2023-02-15  2023-02-01
#2 2023-03-04 2023-04-17  2023-04-08
```

Note that `map2_vec` was introduced in `purrr 1.0.0`. It is useful especially in this case, because `mapply` or previous `purrr::map` functions [notoriously failed](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/358) in returning a date object.

---

Before `purrr 1.0.0`, you can use `map` in combination with `lubridate::as_date`:

```r
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(random_date = as_date(map2_dbl(start_date, end_date, \(x, y) sample(seq.Date(x, y, by = "day"), 1))))
```

Comment: I'm not able to use this solution because I'm not able to download the latest version of r on my work computer

Comment: Check my edit. You can use `as_date`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using seq and sample, as you've done in your provided attempt.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(start_date = c("02/01/2023", "03/04/2023"), 
                 end_date = c("02/15/2023", "04/17/2023"))
df %>% 
  mutate(start_date = as.Date(start_date, format="%m/%d/%Y"),
         end_date = as.Date(end_date, format="%m/%d/%Y")) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(random_date = (seq(start_date, end_date, by="days"))[sample(length(seq(start_date, end_date, by="days")), 1)])

Solution:
      start_date end_date   random_date
      <date>     <date>     <date>     
    1 2023-02-01 2023-02-15 2023-02-09 
    2 2023-03-04 2023-04-17 2023-03-31
```